# Setting pins as output Code - micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, code, msp

So i am using the MSP432 and i am confused on how the code for setting pin to desired function works.

so for example from the manual i have found that:

```
  PxIE = 0b // means that x pin is dsiabled
  PxIE = 1b// means that x pin is enabled
```

now if we have the code shown below:

```
  P1IE |= 0x02 // what does this code do
```

i understand that | means or and that 0x02 is hexadecimal for 0b10 so how does that make the pin 1 enabled?

Comment: First is: check what operators like |=  or ^=  or ~=& means. Then grab a datasheet and look into register maps. P1IE is Pin 1 Interrupt Enable. Go to Interrupts section and familiarise yourself with interrupts settings and registers.

Comment: @smajli i know what those operators do.. but i am not sure how they work with hexadecimals. if its binary values for example P1IE |= 1 i would understand this but i am not sure how it works with hexadecimals

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be dependant of your IDE (or pre-processor) anyway most of them are smart enough to recognise that you are using binary, octal, decimal or hexadecimal values. Anyway, by typing 0b0001 or 01 or 0x1 or 1 you specifying that you using binary, oct, hex or dec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that variety of microcontroller but the standard is to use a zero base for the pin numbering and the binary pattern is a one to one mapping to the pins.

```
Pin   76543210
PxIE  00000010b // = 0x02 Pin 1 is enabled.
```

The `|=` operator is bitwise inclusive OR and assignment operator.  C |= 2 is same as C = C | 2. So in your example,

```
P1IE |= 0x02
```

is the same as

```
P1IE = P1IE | 0x02
```

and if P1IE = 8, for example then adding

```
P1IE = 00001000b
0x02 = 00000010b
       ---------
       00001010b = 0x0A = 10 (decimal)
```

See [C++ operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm).

---

From comment:

> Why do we use 0x02?

0x02 = 10b so that enables the second pin, pin 1.

> How does 00001010b mean its enabled.. it says that a binary value of 1 means it enabled how does 00001010b = 1

It doesn't. The syntax in your question means that pin 1 is enabled along with whatever pins are alread enabled.

```
// Another example
// Bits   76543210
// P1IE = 01101000b // Bits 6, 5 and 3 are already set.
// We now want to set bit 1 as well
//        00000010b = 0x02
```

We can do this without knowing what bits are already set by using the "bitwise inclusive OR" operator.

```
 P1IE |= 0x02               // One way of doing it.
 P1IE |= 0x00000010b        // Another way.
 P1IE = P1IE | 0x00000010b  // Another way.
```

Comment: why do we use 0x02?, and how does 00001010b mean its enabled.. it says that a binary value of 1 means it enabled how does 00001010b = 1?

Answer (score -4):

You have the wrong syntax and identifiers for an MSP432. Maybe you are reading documentation for the MSP430?

If you are using CMSIS-style code on the MSP432, you would use commands like

```
P2->DIR |= BIT3; // set pin P2.3 to output mode
P2->OUT |= BIT3; // set pin P2.3 state to 1
```

See chapter 12 in the MSP432 Technical Reference Manual for a description of all of the registers used by the GPIO ports.

Comment: i named it wrong i am not trying to put it as an output.. its the interrupt.. besides that doesnt matter i am just asking how the operation works the hexadecimal and operators work